# What prevents the use of auxiliary radar installations to allow radar control and MSAW protection in areas that would otherwise be masked by terrain?

Tags: radar, msaw

Both primary<sup>1</sup> and secondary<sup>2</sup> radar, while extremely useful (nay, *indispensable*) for modern aviation and air traffic control, are limited to seeing only aircraft in their direct line of sight; if there is something solid, such as a mountain, between an aircraft and the local radar installation, the aircraft will be invisible to radar.

This means that:

- The aircraft masked by terrain will not show up on the controllers’ radarscopes, forcing them to rely on manual position and altitude reports from the pilots (and, thus, indirectly increasing the pilots’ workload as well), assuming that such reports are even *available* from the pilots (since, if the ATC facility’s radiocommunications transceivers are in the same, or almost the same, location as the radars [which is frequently the case], the terrain responsible for blocking radar transmissions from reaching the aircraft will generally *also* block VHF voice communications between the aircraft and ATC).
- The various automatic protections provided to aircraft under radar coverage will be unavailable; these include MSAW (**M**inimum **S**afe **A**ltitude **W**arning), which alerts the controllers to aircraft in danger of colliding with the ground, and conflict alert, which alerts the controllers to aircraft in danger of colliding with each other.

The latter of these two effects has contributed to [at least one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_Airlines_Flight_1572) accident (as always, my emphasis unless noted otherwise):

> **1.18.1.3 Minimum Safe Altitude Warning (MSAW)**
>
> MSAW is a computer program to warn a controller when an airplane descends or will descend below a predetermined altitude. **The MSAW at BDL was programmed to provide an alarm if the aircraft’s Mode C transponder transmitted two signals when the airplane was at or below 1,050 feet msl. However, if the radar does not pick up the aircraft’s mode C transponder signal, the program cannot function. The BDL approach control radar system produced an MSAW alarm for flight 1572 at 0055:39. The radar tracking data showed that when this alarm was produced, the aircraft was at 800 feet msl and the aircraft had already struck the trees.** FAA personnel stated that under normal circumstances, the MSAW should have produced an audible alarm at that time in the tower cab, and a visual alarm should have occurred on the radar display and on the DBRITE [bright radar indicator tower equipment] in the radar room and tower cab.
>
> **Radar tracking data showed no radar "hits" from flight 1572’s mode C transponder between 0055:23 and 0055:32, and also none between 0055:05 and 0055:23.** The radar antenna produces returns about every 4.5 seconds. **FAA personnel reported that the reason for the absence of these hits was the shielding of the airplane from the radar by the ridge line. FAA technicians later explained that if the radar could not "paint" the airplane, the MSAW computer program could not warn the controller that the airplane was at an unsafe altitude.**
>
> **According to FAA equipment design personnel, if a steady stream of Mode C information had been available to the computer, the MSAW alarm would have sounded as soon as the aircraft descended past 1,100 feet msl.** They indicated that on final approach, a standardized set of MSAW parameters is used, not taking into account obstacles such as the ridge. **BDL FAA personnel said that in an attempt to improve radar coverage prior to the accident, they had changed or optimized the tilt on the radar antenna, but that the ridge still obstructed radar coverage.**  *[NTSB [AAR-96/05](https://www.ntsb.gov/investigations/AccidentReports/Reports/AAR9605.pdf), pages 53-54 (pages 61-62 of the PDF file of the report); section heading bolded in original.]*
>
> [...]
>
> **2.7.3 MSAW (Minimum Safe Altitude Warning)**
>
> MSAW is a computer program to warn a controller when an airplane descends or will descend below a predetermined altitude. **If the radar does not receive a signal from a target, the program cannot function.** The MSAW at BDL was set to alarm if the aircraft transmitted two mode C returns at or below 1,050 feet msl (30 feet below the MDA for the runway 15 VOR approach). **There was no alarm as flight 1572 descended below the MDA because the aircraft was not in radar contact at that point because of shielding by the ridge line.** There was a radar return recorded at 1,300 feet (above the MSAW envelope) **but because of shielding from the ridge, the aircraft was out of radar contact for three radar sweeps and was therefore not visible to the controllers. Then, a single radar return was recorded at 900 feet, followed by another radar sweep with no recording of the flight, and then two radar returns were recorded at 800 feet.** The MSAW then sounded an alarm, as it should have under those conditions.<sup>35</sup> **However, this alarm sounded about 4 seconds after the airplane had struck the trees.**
>
> ---
>
> <sup>35</sup>**Two consecutive sweeps with radar contact with an airplane are required to set off the MSAW alarm.** This is the reason that the MSAW did not alarm following the single radar contact at 900 feet.
>
> ---
>
> **According to the FAA, because of the lack of radar coverage close to the ridge, the minimums for the VOR 15 approach would have to be raised to give MSAW protection for this approach.** It is not desirable for an MSAW alarm to occur above the MDA. This would result in an MSAW false alarm sounding on every approach, making the occasional valid alarm likely to be ineffective. **Because the last radar return before the airplane struck the trees was recorded at 1,300 feet, the lowest altitude at which the MSAW could be programmed to activate and be effective is 1,300 feet. Therefore, to have full MSAW coverage, the approach minimums for this approach would have to be raised from 1,080 feet msl to somewhat above 1,300 feet msl,** to keep the MDA above the alarm point for the MSAW. However, an MDA this high would defeat the purpose of the instrument approach. The descent from a 1,350-foot MDA to the runway would have to start far back along the final approach course, and the ceiling and visibility minimums would be unrealistically high. The Safety Board therefore concludes that despite the lack of full MSAW coverage along the approach, the MSAW operated properly, **and that because of topographical limitations of the BDL local area, it is not practical to provide full MSAW coverage.**  *[Pages 75-76 (83-84); section heading (again) bolded in original.]*

A potential solution would be to place auxiliary radars on areas of obstructively-high terrain (especially areas of high terrain that would be especially prone to having aircraft behind them, such as - for instance - large hills and ridges along airport nonprecision-approach paths), allowing radar coverage, and its associated protections, to be extended to even aircraft masked from the primary radar’s view.

Why (other than cost, which must necessarily take a backseat to improvements in aviation safety) is this not done?

---

<sup>1</sup>: Radar which works by bouncing radio waves off aircraft (and also anything else that happens to be in the air).

<sup>2</sup>: “Radar” which works by sending out a talk-to-me signal and listening for replies from aircraft transponders.

Comment: Cost.  Ground-based radar is expensive. Especially compared to EGPWS.

Comment: @RalphJ: Feel free to make that an answer.